# yii CGridView show only logged-in user's records in many_many relation

Tags: yii

I have two tables:
 `user` and `asset` and there is `user_asset` table that makes many_many relation

Now I want to show only the assets related with logged-in user in CGridView (`user_id` comes from `Yii::app()->user->id`)

How to write a criteria that makes it possible?

Comment: Have you set up relations between the tables in the model classes?

Comment: yes there are relations - 'assets' in user model and 'users' in asset model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work, adding this inside the Model class's search method:

```
    $criteria->with=array(
      'users'  
    );
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->condition = "users_users.user_id='".Yii::app()->user->id."'";
```

... and inside CActiveDataProvider declaration:

```
'criteria'=>array(
    'with' => 'users',
    'together'=>true,
    'condition'=>'users_users.user_id = '.Yii::app()->user->id,
),
```

Maybe not the best way but does what needed. `users_users` is sql table alias by Yii, I got a hint from error message :)

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to define your relations in both of the model

user:

```
'assets' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Asset', 'user_asset(user_id, asset_id)'),
```

asset:

```
'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Asset', 'user_asset(asset_id, user_id)'),
```

2) You Create a dataProvider that will fetch only the recquired datas (define it in a model (best) or a controller bu not in a view):

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Asset', array(
'criteria'=>array(
    'with'=>array(
        'users'=>array(
            'condition' => 'id = ' . Yii::app()->user->id
         ),
     ),
),
 ...
));
```

3) You give to your CGridView the good provider:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ...
));
```

The code is given as example, you should adapt it to your need!

Comment: It gave me sql error on `id=...`, changed to `t.id=...` and error disappeared but still didn't work as expected. Solution is in my answer.